# Does nexus 4 work with indian network

Tags: sim-card, nexus-4

I had bought a nexus 4 from US & right now.. i am trying to use it in india, with Vodafone SIM. I am facing problem, as the phone doesnt detect any SIM. Please guide whether Nexus 4 can be used with Vodafone network

Answer (score 0):

Yes. My two friends using Nexus 4(16GB&8GB) in India. They didn't get any issues.
You can use Micro Sim bought from carrier or a manual cut version of ordinary SIM.